# Eclipse - Enlarging context information window

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I am programming in Java and when clicking Ctrl+Shift+Space when the cursor is inside a function with multiple versions a list of the versions appear. Unfortunately the window that displays this information is very small on my computer (Ubuntu). I tried enlarging the window by dragging the corner outwards but that doesn't work. The size of the window doesn't change when I close and reopen Eclipse which leads me to believe that there is a configuration file somewhere that controls this. Is there a config file that stores the size of the context information window and if so where is it?

Answer (score 0):

I also googled around and found your post before actually trying it out of despair.

Turns out i just need to hover at the right-bottom-corner of the popup and click and then drag it down to enlarge.

The rests of the context information popups anywhere will have the same size of your last resize.